# Continuous Function and Open Subsets in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $E$ be a subset in $\mathbb R$, $f$ a real-value function on $E$.
Prove that $f$ is continuous on $E\iff$ for every open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(V)$ in open relative to $E$.

My question is about the ($\Rightarrow$) direction only.
Let $f$ be a continuous function on $E$ and $V$ a open subset on $\mathbb R$.
If $f^{-1}(V)=\{\}$, then it is open.  Suppose that $f^{-1}(V)\neq\{\}$. Let $p\in f^{-1}(V)$.
Then $f(p)\in V$.  Select $\epsilon$ such that $N_\epsilon(f(p))\subset V$.

My question is this.  At this point, we do not know if $p$ is an element of $E$.
If $p\in E$, since $f$ is continuous on $E$, $\exists\delta$ such that $f(x)\in N_\epsilon(f(p))$ for all $x\in N_\delta(p)\cap E$.
Thus $N_\delta(p)\cap E\subset f^{-1}(V)$.

But, suppose that $p\notin E$.  How do I know that the above statement is still true?
I tried the following:
Let $q\in E$ be a point such that $f(q)\in N_\epsilon(f(p))$
Select $\alpha$ such that $N_\alpha(f(q))\in N_\epsilon(f(p))$.
Then $\exists\delta$ such that $f(x)\in N_\alpha(f(q))$ for all $x\in N_\delta(q)\cap E$.
But this only shows that $N_\delta(q)\cap E\subset f^{-1}(V)$, not $N_\delta(p) ....$
I also thought about showing that if $p\notin E$, then $N_\delta(p)\cap E=\{\}$,
but I have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: You're worrying unnecessarily. You should be assuming $f^{-1}(V)\cap E\ne\emptyset$ and choosing $p\in f^{-1}(V)\cap E$.

Comment: I have a suggestion for your math formatting. You should put entire mathematical expressions in dollar signs. For instance, instead of $f^{-1}$(V) = {} it should be $f^{-1}(V)=\{\}$ which is written `$f^{-1}(V)=\{\}$`.

Comment: Note that: You can replace R by any other metric space.

Comment: @Peter you must assume the standart definition, the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ one (always in metric spaces this is the standart definition, for the contrary in topological spaces is the definition with open sets)

Comment: @GastónBurrull Well, one can use the definition using open balls: for each open ball $B_0=B(f(a);\epsilon)$ there is an open ball $B_1=B(a;\delta)$ such that $B_1\subseteq f^{-1}(B_0)$. And open balls form a basis for the topology, so it becomes nicer.

Comment: @GastónBurrull Of course there is none, but for people new to topological idea, it might need to sink in a little. The point is that open balls form a basis for the open sets, and we define continuity in metric spaces precisely in terms of those, which might not be *that* evident in the first place.

Comment: @GastónBurrull Eh... lo digo en castellano a ver si queda mas claro: Si, la definición de continuidad mas antigua es la "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" y la definición de continuidad usando preimagenes de abiertos es mas moderna, pero lo que quiero decir es que una simple traducción nos permite escribir la definición mas antigua en términos de bolas abiertas, que quiza es mas apropiada para motivar, enfrentar y entender la generalización, ¿si? Mejor si limpiamos un poco estos comentarios casi inútiles.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8975/discussion-between-gaston-burrull-and-peter-tamaroff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change only one step in your proof:

When you say:

"If $f^{-1}(V)=\{\}$ then it is open"

reeplace by

"If $f^{-1}(V)\cap E=\{\}$" then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open relative to $E$".

Then the following line must be

"suppose now $f^{-1}(V)\cap E\neq\{\}$ then exists $p\in f^{-1}(V)\cap E$"

and your problem was solved since $p\in E$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  After all the work, I entirely forgot where I was starting from ....

Comment: Glad to be of help.